# Why does "git tag -l" return different listings for my coworker and me?

Tags: git, tags

My colleague created a tag for a particular version of our code.  He named it "x".  Today, I wanted to get "x" for myself, so I did

`git tag -l`.

As a result I got a listing of "y".

I asked him to do the same thing (`git tag -l`).  He did so, and he sees two listings: "x" and "y".  He did a git status; it says he's clean and has nothing to commit.

**Why can't I see both listings?**  Other questions and sites I've seen imply that `git tag -l` is all that's needed to see all listings.

Comment: Did you get all refs from the remote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your co-worker has not pushed the tags upstream into the remote.

- Ask your co-worker to run this command if he has not already done it:

  ```
  git push <REMOTE-NAME> --tags
  ```
- Then you must run a fetch to get the refs corresponding to the tags into your local repo:

  ```
  git fetch <REMOTE-NAME> --tags
  ```
- Run `git tags -l` again to see if you see the same set of tags that your co-worker sees.

Comment: Nice.  That did it; he ran the push with --tags and I ran the fetch with --tags.  Thanks!  I apparently can accept your answer in 11 minutes.